# Ways to change algorithm to set rows height in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, uitableview

What am I having:

- `var size: CGFloat = 21.0`
- TableView with actions    **cellForRowAtIndexPath** and
  **heightForRowAtIndexPath**

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** I'm setting a string into **textLabel** and saving **textLabel.frame.height** into **size** vairable

Then in **heightForRowAtIndexPath** I'm returning **size** variable

The problem is that **heightForRow** executes before **cellForRow** and I need to reload table view for two times. But if there are a lot of cells - some of invisible will not be reloaded and their size will not be changes.

How can I make this algorithm work properly in all cases without reloading twice?

**Update**:

Here how is my label set by autolayout in prototype cell

[image]

It does not have bottom constraint

**Update 2**:

Here it is project file [sendspace.com/file/816z35](http://sendspace.com/file/816z35)

Comment: You can calculate the height of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` instead of in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Too good to be the truth. By changing label in cell it changes its height which next must be set as row height. I can not set row height before printing string into label

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich why not, you can calculate the height of a `NSString` and return that in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich can you please send me your project I will send you the updated one

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich It's really simple and which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: ok, here it is https://www.sendspace.com/file/816z35 (I'm trying to make chat demo application)

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the height in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of `UITableView`.

One approach would be to manually get the size by calling `sizeWithAttributes:` on your string (NSString).

Something like this:

```
var texts = ["some text 1", "some text 2"]
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let string = texts[indexPath.row] as NSString
    return string.sizeWithAttributes(attributes).height
}
```

---

Or a better approach (performance-wise) would be to calculate the heights when you first get the texts for the cells. Something like this:

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)]
var sizes = [CGFloat]()
var texts: [String] = ["some text 1", "some text 2"] {
    didSet {
        sizes = []
        for text in texts {
            let string = text as NSString
            let height = string.sizeWithAttributes(attributes).height
            sizes.append(height)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return sizes[indexPath.row]
}
```

---

Both code examples weren't tested, but they should generally work and might need some adjustments to fit your case.

---

**UPDATE**

To get the multi-line height constrained to some width you can do this:

```
let string = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
let size = string.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(YOUR_WIDTH, CGFloat.max), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
let height = size.height
```

Comment: thank you very much for you trying, but it's not work properly in my case. I've updated my post to show label settings. Depended of them string become multilined and it's height changes to those which must set in row height

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich see the update to my answer. It's just he part where you get the multiline height of the label, don't forget to add your top constraint constant value to it, to get the actual cell size and change `YOUR_WIDTH` to the width of the cell minus the left and right constraint.

Comment: I will pass your information through, thanks. I'll be very grateful if you look at project files I've posted in comment to my questions for a while :)

Comment: I've also added the link into question as an "Update 2". Thanks in advance

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich I've modified your view controller a little, but this should be the main idea. http://pastebin.com/AbBmbfqq

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich "Not working at all" isn't a very good explanation of the problem. I've personally tested this (similar) code and I have it in multiple released apps on App Store working without any problems. This is indeed the right solution to your problem, but your problem lays somewhere else in your code or whole project setup. Try reading more about table views and custom cells in general.